# Desktop Icons, Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome, 18.10, desktop-icons

I recently Installed Ubuntu 18.10 and downloaded `gnome-tweaks` to customise. I used it for a while and had disabled the icons on the desktop with this tool, but when I wanted to activate them again, I did not see the desktop options in tweaks.

So I could no longer retrieve my Icons on the desktop. Could someone help me recover them? I use Gnome 3.30

Answer (score 1):

from the same `Gnome-Tweaks` application you can turn on and off the "Icons on Desktop" button or it sub options as shown below.

[image: screenshot]

or you can turn on and off the "Icons on Desktop" button
by the below commands in terminal.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```